# Visual Studio 2022: all file locations in bookmark suddenly bacame uppercase

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Today I opened my solution and suddenly all the *File Location paths* in the *Bookmarks window* became upper case.

I did nothing special, no Visual Studio upgrades, no solution or project global changes.
The project version from couple of days before is just fine.

I see that the changes touched the `.vs\<solution name>\v17\.suo` file, the names in it became upper case.

Two questions:

1. What could have caused this change?
2. Is there any way to fix this back without substituting the .suo file (risky because of other possible changes) and without reentering all bookmarks?

Since I use camel case file names, this is in may way to read names of the files.

Comment: pressing `ctrl+shift+U` will turn the selected text upper case, I don't know if it works only in the editor or also on other parts of the IDE. Maybe you pressed that combination by error?

Comment: @JohnDoe, no; this combination works for editor only and doesn't work in *Bookmarks window*. I just checked both it and opposite one (Ctrl+U for lower case) in *Bookmarks window*; nothing changes and bell sound says that this is a wrong input for this window.